# InterruptedException is not being caught

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm learning Java concurrency, and tried an example from Java tutorial, with a little experiment (try to catch the exception).

```
public class SleepMessages {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String importantInfo[] = {
            "Mares eat oats",
            "Does eat oats",
            "Little lambs eat ivy",
            "A kid will eat ivy too"
        };

        try { // my experiment
            for (int i = 0; i < importantInfo.length; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(4000);
                System.out.println(importantInfo[i]);
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            System.out.println("caught InterruptedException");
        }
    }
}
```

And I tried sending it an interrupt signal outside, by "kill -2 $PID".

I expected that while the processing was sleeping, the signal would cause Thread.sleep() to throw the exception, and then I could catch it, but actually not!

Could anyone explain why?
(I'm wondering maybe it's my way sending the signal (kill -2) is not correct.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to handle SIGINT signals from outside, is to register a [shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) in your appliation:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.println("Shutdown hook called!");
            }
        });

        while (true)
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when you start your program and kill it with `kill -2 <PID>` the shutdown hook will be invoked and you can gracefully shutdown.

Catching `InterruptedException` (what you want to do) is possible when you are interrupting your thread **from inside your application** using `interrupt()` as the following very basic example demonstrates:

```
public class Main
{
   public static void main( final String[] args )
   {

      final Thread t1 = new Thread()
      {
         @Override
         public void run()
         {
            try
            {
               while ( true )
               {
                  Thread.sleep( 1000 );
               }

            }
            catch ( final InterruptedException e )
            {
               System.out.println( "This thread was interrupted!" );
            }
         }
      };
      t1.start();
      t1.interrupt();
   }
}
```

br

Answer (score 2):

`InterruptedException` is caught when you call `Thread.interrupt()` on the thread in question. It has nothing whatsoever to do with the `kill` program.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same scenario on my ubuntu machine, and found that when we use kill command to kill a process, then It basically kill a entire process, So this behavior is like `System.exit(1)`, But the interrupted exception is something different, where the interrupted status flag is set to tell the thread that it has been received interrupt from some other thread, one more thing,  if some other thread will interrupt this thread by calling interrupt() method on this thread instance then you will get `InterruptedException` only if current thread was sleeping or waiting state. If the thread is running then calling `interrupt()` method on it will just set the interrupt flag to true (to check interrupt status flag, you can check via `isInterrupted()` method on this thread instance), and will not throw `InterruptedException`.

See below code, here I have used System.exit(1), in a different thread, and you will see that the whole Java process was exited,  there is no interrupted exception, because of the reasons explained above.

```
     public static void main(String args[]) {
        String importantInfo[] = {
                "Mares eat oats",
                "Does eat oats",
                "Little lambs eat ivy",
                "A kid will eat ivy too"
        };

        try { // my experiment
            while(true) {
                Thread.sleep(4000);
                Thread t = new Thread() {
                  public void run() {
                      try {
                          Thread.sleep(1000);
                          System.exit(1);
                      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      }
                  }
                };
                t.start();

                System.out.println(importantInfo[0]);
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            System.out.println("caught InterruptedException");
        }
    }
```

**Output of above modified code:**

> Mares eat oats
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code, and do use it for text that is.